# How do you get a count of a subquery in Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, subquery, rails-activerecord

I'm migrating an SQL query to Active Record. Here is a simplified version:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
  SELECT type, date(created_at)
  FROM notification_messages
  GROUP BY type, date(created_at)
) x
```

I'm not sure how to implement this in Active Record. This works, but it's messy:

```
sql = NotificationMessage.
  select("type, date(created_at) AS period").
  group("type", "period").
  to_sql
NotificationMessage.connection.exec_query("SELECT count(*) FROM (#{sql}) x")
```

Another possibility is to do the count in Ruby, but that would be less efficient:

```
NotificationMessage.
  select("type, date(created_at) AS period").
  group("type", "period").
  length
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rails has the [`from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from) method. So I would write it:

```
NotificationMessage
  .from(
    NotificationMessage
      .select("type, date(created_at)")
      .group("type, date(created_at)"), :x
  ).count
```