# Rails sub select query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to Sub Select using Rails `ActiveRecord`?

```sql
SELECT * FROM ( 
 < sub query > 
) as T
GROUP BY <COLUMN_NAME> ORDER BY <ANOTHER_COLUMN> DESC
```

I got the subquery part using `ActiveRecord`. However, I am trying to get the whole thing done using `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: How about ...select * from users where users.id IN <sub query>.....

Comment: Could you please post your whole query?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a better way or not, but I ended up doing this for now.

[How do you get a count of a subquery in Active Record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517078/how-do-you-get-a-count-of-a-subquery-in-active-record)